# Azure pipeline for a wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-git-deployment

I am currently hosting a website using an azure app service (wordpress) and I want to setup a pipeline that basically pushes a build artifact from my github repo to the themes directory and syncs it with the current one. Is this even possible? Any point in the right direction is massively helpful. Thank you.

Comment: If i am correct the themes directory is just a folder and doesn't need to resync for the changes to apply to the site. You could make a build pipeline where you make the artifacts from the git repo with the theme and then a release pipeline where you place the artifact in the theme directory. In the release pipeline you can select the task copy files. With this task you can copy them into the directory.

Comment: Your basically correct, yes, it needs to overright any files that have been updated in the repo. Where can I find a way of writing this type of pipeline? Are there tutorials anywhere?